# Is there a way to control Cursor Point in std::fstream?

Tags: c++, c++17, fstream

I'm reading big datas from .txt file(s) like 1000-5000 persons data. and they saved in a file with alegorithm that i can easily read datas back. but to do it more easy, I'm seeking the way to control File cursor point.

for example in `console app` you can use VT100 Escape sequences like `\033[3A` (3 line up) `\033[2D` (2 Letter Left) `\0337` (Save Position)

So is there way to control cursor point like that?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::istream::seekg()` et al.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not really, because I'm not struggling with searcing datas, when I found, my problem is I have to push_back 2 Lines above to the string. And I don't want to rescan file untill i reach 2 lines up point

Comment: There's no such thing. You can read whole lines and store these in a `std::vector<std::string>` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::fstream` can be seen as a linear stream of single bytes. As this, there is no way to use something like "cursor up" which as `std::fstream` has no knowledge of lines in the file.

What you can do is asking for the current position you are currently reading [tellg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)or writing with [tellp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp).

After keeping such positions, you can go back with [seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) or [seekp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp).

If you like you can store current line positions while reading the file and navigate later with this stored position. Alternatively, if you modify the file in a random fashion and the file is not such big, you can read it completely to a data structure of your choice, modify the data internally and write it back later.

Comment: Thank you for useful answer, Maybe I'll store 'n' lines in vector where every data iterates to another person. so if i found data in middle of the persons data, I can read back from vector.

Comment: Due to i read datas with lines, I set counter that counts lines, and I get informations where i want

Comment: Sorry, Forgot that ':D

Comment: @AhmetYusufYatkın Thanks :-)